# Trouble changing port in Confluent 2.0.0 Kafka 0.9

Tags: apache-kafka

Seeing some strange behavior with Confluent 2.0.0 Kafka 0.9, wondering if anyone has any ideas.  I had started up a broker with the PLAINTEXT listener, on 9092.  worked great.  I am trying to change it to listen to a different port.  I tried 9095.  When it starts up I see this in the log:

```
[2016-01-14 18:11:43,511] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9095. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
```

But then later, I see this

```
[2016-01-14 18:11:43,906] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: PLAINTEXT -> EndPoint(ec2-54-164-3-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com,9092,PLAINTEXT) (kafka.utils.ZkUtils)
```

This is concerning, why is it still registering on 9092???

At this point, if I try to produce on 9095 I get tons of these until I kill it:

```
[2016-01-14 18:14:42,614] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {plaintext=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2016-01-14 18:14:42,745] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {plaintext=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2016-01-14 18:14:42,850] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {plaintext=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
...
```

And if I try to produce on 9092 it fails after 1 minute with this:

```
[2016-01-14 18:30:11,845] ERROR Error when sending message to topic plaintext with key: null, value: 10 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

I think this may have something to do with my host names not being set up properly... but I'm not sure how to do that... FYI this is an EC2 instance.  hostname is ip-10-0-0-22.  /etc/hosts has

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

The public DNS is ec2-54-164-3-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com.  And in my server.properties I have

```
advertised.host.name=ec2-54-164-3-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

(This last I found I had to set to be able to connect to the broker from outside of amazon).

So... any suggestions from any Kafka experts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use advertised.listeners.  I bet Alexander Zolotko's suggestion to use advertised.port would have worked too, although I didn't try tat.

Answer (score 0):

There's `advertised.port` property which you can explicitly set to `9095`.